# Phonegap 3.0, Android filetransfer download not accessible

Tags: android, html, cordova

Some background...After downloading a file with FileTransfer.download , I cannot read the file contents.  Phonegap claims the file is there and gives me the path.  The metadata can be read but FileReader does not see any contents.

I downloaded Android File Transfer for Mac to see if the files were 'physically' there but it doesn't show the files either.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Android 4.3, same code worked just fine.